# can I delete a whole branch from a git repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm not just talking about the branch pointer :-)

Say I have a already fully merged branch, and now I want to make it look like that branch never existed. It seems to me I should be able to completely prune that branch from the repo (i.e. delete all the commits on that branch so it never shows in the history) without sacrificing the integrity. Is there any way to do that?

Would it be possible to push the remaining branch upstream without pushing the one i'd rather forget?

EDIT: I've added in an example to try and illustrate this better

```
git checkout master
git commit -m "C1"
git branch b1
git commit -m "C2"
git checkout b1
git commit -m "C3"
git checkout master
git merge -m "C4" b1
git branch -d b1
```

gives this result

```
--C1--+----C2----+--C4
       \        /
        +--C3--+
```

what I want to do is delete C3 but leave C4 exactly as it is, so that the history looks linear. It seems to me the sha-1 of C4 will be the same whether or not C3 is there, so I don't understand why I should need to rebase/cherry pick to do it

Comment: You know a branch is a pointer. Suppose you have two names, Tom and Jack. You are the commit, Jack and Tom are two branches. What would happen to Tom if one deletes the name Jack and prunes the commit you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to delete a branch completely:

```
git branch -D branchname
git push origin :branchname
```

`-D` is force to delete the branch even the branch has not merged.

Comment: it seems to me this is just deleting the branch pointer. I want to delete the actual branch itself (i.e. all the commits which were on that branch)

Comment: @Andy If you delete the branch and the commits were not pointed to by any other ref (branch, tag...) then the garbage collector will clean them out. If they _are_ referred to by other refs, you can't get rid of them "without sacrificing the integrity".

Comment: @Andy, actually it delete the branch not pointer. Just as Dan Lowe said, if some commits of the branch are also as parts of other branches, so you can't delete these commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the following commands:

```
git branch -D branchname.
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
git repack -a -d -l
```

More information on each command is available on git documentation:https://git-scm.com/docs

Answer (score -1):

Have you try using :

`$git branch -d` ?